# help with tableless design (floating divs)

Tags: php, html, layout

How can I achieve a similar structure of blocks like on this page: http://www.sovietrussia.org/o

Basically I need one block (like the image) to be on the left, and all other blocks take up all of the right side and below at 100% width. If a block on the right side passes the left image block then it will go below it and take up the width of the page 100%

Comment: I have tried to float the image block, the other blocks stay on the right but they take up 100% width even when the text inside the block is short.

Answer (score 1):

this will be set your image in left and all remaining text in right of the image.....!

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .setwet{
    float:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    }
    .setwetpic{
    float:left
    }
    br{
    clear:both;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <span class="setwetpic"><img src="image.gif" /></span><span class="setwet">Name:waqas <br />Auther: Waqas</span><br/><span class="setwetpic"><img src="image.gif" /></span><span class="setwet">Name:waqas <br />Auther: Waqas</span>

    </div>
      </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float the image with `style="float: left;"`.  Everything will lay out to its right.  When you want to force everything to be full width, place an element with `style="clear: bloth;"` to clear the float.

Comment: When I do this the blocks besides the image have 100% width even when the amount of text is short.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a CSS grid layout system

There are 4 different one available at http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/